# What is the C++ equivalent of the C# @ symbol prefixing strings?

Tags: c++, escaping

What is the C++ equivalent of the C# @ symbol prefixing strings? For escaping symbols automatically?

Example: `var howManySlashesAreThereIn = @"\\\\\\"`;

Comment: possible duplicate of [String literals C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597322/string-literals-c)

Comment: @Jake - Gotcha! Thanx for the clarification.  The .Net term is  "verbatim string literal", and the purpose is so that "\" isn't treated as an escape character:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx.    There is no equivalent in either Java or current versions of C++ (and no, I *don't* consider C++11 a "current version" ;))

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In C++11, you can use raw string literals:

```
std::string s = R"(This\is\a\raw\string\literal)";

std::string s = R"*(This \one contains \a )", which would normally end the string)*";
```

Here's the [C++11 FAQ](http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#raw-strings) word on it, and a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for the "raw string" feature of C++ but it's a fairly recent addition (C++11, I believe).

```
std::string howManySlashesAreThereIn = R"(\\\\\\)";
```

It's documented in `2.14.5 String lieterals` of the C++11 standard, though that tome may be a little dry for you, so I'd suggest googling up on `"raw string" c++`.

As well as getting rid of those escape doubling monstrosites like `"\\\\nasbox\\sharename\\downloads\\super_sekrit_stuff"`, it also allows you to bypass the "adding `\n` characters and combining adjacent strings" trick such as turning:

```
htmlString =
    "<HTML>\n"
      "<HEAD>\n"
        "<TITLE>My page</TITLE>\n"
        "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n"
      "</HEAD>\n"
      "<BODY LINK=\"#0000ff\" VLINK=\"#800080\" BGCOLOR=\"#ffffff\">\n"
        "<P> </P>\n"
        "<PRE>\n";
```

into something more readable (not *exactly* the same due to spaces in the second variant, but perfectly okay for HTML since it ignores the added spaces in this case):

```
htmlString = R"xyzzy(
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <TITLE>My page</TITLE>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      </HEAD>
      <BODY LINK="#0000ff" VLINK="#800080" BGCOLOR="#ffffff">
        <P> </P>
        <PRE>
    )xyzzy";
```

Comment: This is old but it's supposed to be `R"( ... )"` in your last example, and it probably shouldn't have a backslash since it's a raw string.

Comment: The first version as written won't have the indentation that the second version shows.  You could move all the left quotes in the old-fashioned version to the left to accumulate white space if you want indentation.  Raw strings are easier to get right.

Answer (score 4):

C++11 adds `raw` string literals that are at least somewhat similar.

```
R"(This is a raw literal)";
```

These are particularly useful for regexes, like:

```
R"@(\w+\d*)@"
```

...which would, as a traditional literal would be:

```
"\\w+\\d*"
```

Although the difference isn't huge, it can make a difference, especially in a longer regex.

Comment: The delimiter `@` must be inside the quotes.

Comment: @user362515: Oops--amazing how a typo can survive for almost 4 years when it doesn't get run through a compiler...