# Create raw text string in C++, analogous to C#'s "@ string"

Tags: c#, c++, string, string-literals

I'm coming to C++ from C#. I have a string with a lot of backslashes in it and I'd like to read the string as raw text. Does C++ have something like C#'s "at string"? For example:

```
string s = @"\\Some\Path";
```

In my C++ file I'm using:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: @MadScienceDreams `R"(string)"` is like C#'s `@"string"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define std::string in C++ without escape characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501599/define-stdstring-in-c-without-escape-characters)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yeah, I always miss the little things of the new standard (its only in c++11)

Comment: I just realized that this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597322/string-literals-c. Somehow I missed this in my search. Closing.

Comment: fatcat1111 you at least helped @MadScienceDreams with your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use raw string literals:

```
std::string s = R"(\Some\Path)";
```

This feature is available in C++11.

Note that for file system paths you can use forward slashes:

```
std::string s = "/Some/Path";
```

Comment: Shouldnt c++ have a standard file separator?

Comment: @aaronman: C++ doesn't even have *files*. Asking for file *separators* is like asking for a divorce before you're even married.

Answer (score 5):

According to the c++11 standard it has raw strings like `R"...."`, I say according to the standard because I have never needed to use them :).
This kind of string can be very useful for things like regexes.